# How to limit access to class function from main function?

Tags: c++, function, class

How to limit access to class function from main function?

Here my code.

```
class Bar
{
public: void doSomething(){}
};

class Foo
{
public: Bar bar;
//Only this scope that bar object was declared(In this case only Foo class)
//Can access doSomething() by bar object.
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar.doSomething(); //doSomething() should be limited(can't access)
    return 0;
}
```

PS.Sorry for my poor English.

---

**Edit**: 
I didn't delete old code but I expand with new code.
I think this case can't use friend class. Because I plan to use for every class. Thanks

```
class Bar
{
public:
    void A() {} //Can access in scope that object of Bar was declared only
    void B() {}
    void C() {}
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Bar bar;
    //Only this scope that bar object was declared(In this case is a Foo class)
    //Foo class can access A function by bar object

    //main function need to access bar object with B, C function
    //but main function don't need to access A function
    void CallA()
    {
        bar.A(); //Correct
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.bar.A(); //Incorrect: A function should be limited(can't access)    
    foo.bar.B(); //Correct
    foo.bar.C(); //Correct
    foo.CallA(); //Correct
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `Foo` a friend of `Bar`

```
class Bar
{
    friend class Foo;
private:
    void doSomething(){}
};
```

And also avoid making member variables `public`. Use `setters/getters` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can define Foo as a friend class of Bar and make doSomething() private.

Answer (score 2):

Making `Bar bar` private inside `Foo` would do the trick, would it not?
Then only the class `Foo` could use `bar`.